# How to write an SQL query that examines the previous row?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table (already sorted) in SQL server with the following:

```
stringname
==========
stringA
stringA
stringB
stringB
stringA
stringC
stringC
stringC
stringA
```

I would like to output the following:

```
stringname previous_stringname count
========== =================== =====
stringA    NULL                1
stringA    stringA             1
stringA    stringB             1
stringA    stringC             1
stringB    stringA             1
stringB    stringB             1
stringC    stringA             1
stringC    stringC             2
```

That is, for each stringname in the original table and for each of that stringname's previous entry, I would like to output it with the number of times it had each previous string (with NULL for the first entry).

How would I write an SQL query for this?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do this easily in SQL. You're better off querying the data and let the program handle the logic.

Comment: look to ROW_NUMBER() and a self join

Comment: ROW_NUMBER won't help because you can't use a constant in an order by. You need another identifier in the table like an `IDENTITY` column in order to insure that the stringnames are queried out in the order you want them.

Comment: What do you mean you have a table "already sorted"? Do you mean that there is a clustered index that you haven't shown us and those rows are in clustered index key order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is not necessary; just use:

```
select b.stringname as stringname, a.stringname as previous_stringname
    into #tmp
    from (select stringname, row_number() over (order by id /* $/0 */) as row from testing) a
    right outer join (select stringname, row_number() over (order by id /* $/0 */) as row from testing) b
    on a.row = b.row - 1;
select *, count(*) as [count] from #tmp group by stringname, previous_stringname;
```

Answer (score 1):

The folllowing will do the trick, but in return for the answer I want you to Google "recursion" and see what Google suggests to search for :)

Clarification: The recursion happens by joining on the row - 1 to row between the temp table and the CTE. This method is dependent on having an independent `IDENTITY` column (`ID` in this case) and uses `ROWNUMBER()` to account for any possible gaps in IDs. Since `ROW_NUMBER()` can't be used in a `JOIN` I had to resort to using a subquery in the recursive part of the `CTE`. Even if you know you have continuous IDs, I'd recommend using the `ROW_NUMBER` for this kind of query anyway just to be safe because gaps will mess it up.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT IDENTITY(1,1),stringname NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT #tmp (stringname)

VALUES
('stringA')
,('stringA')
,('stringB')
,('stringB')
,('stringA')
,('stringC')
,('stringC')
,('stringC')
,('stringA')

;WITH StringNames
AS(
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Row  --Accounts for gaps in ID
    ,stringname 
    ,CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS previous_stringname     
FROM #tmp
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Row
    ,t.stringname
    ,s.stringname AS previous_stringname
    FROM (
            SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Row --Accounts for gaps in ID 
            ,stringname
            FROM #tmp) AS t
JOIN StringNames AS s ON t.row - 1 = s.row
)

SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    stringname
    ,previous_stringname
    ,COUNT(*) AS count  
 FROM StringNames
 GROUP BY 
    stringname
    ,previous_stringname
ORDER BY stringname
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wil, why do you need the identity column?

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #table (stringname NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT  #table (stringname)
VALUES  ('stringA')
        ,('stringA')
        ,('stringB')
        ,('stringB')
        ,('stringA')
        ,('stringC')
        ,('stringC')
        ,('stringC')
        ,('stringA')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH [cteRowNumbers] AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $/0) AS [RowNumber],
            [stringname],
            CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [previous_stringname]
    FROM #table
)
,[cteStringNames] AS (
    SELECT  [RowNumber], 
            [stringname], 
            [previous_stringname]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 1 
                [RowNumber], 
                [stringname], 
                [previous_stringname]
        FROM [cteRowNumbers]
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.[RowNumber],
            t.[stringname],
            s.[stringname] AS [previous_stringname]
    FROM [cteRowNumbers] AS t
    INNER JOIN [cteStringNames] AS s 
        ON t.[RowNumber] - 1 = s.[RowNumber]
)

SELECT  [stringname],
        [previous_stringname],
        COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM [cteStringNames]
GROUP BY stringname, previous_stringname
ORDER BY stringname
```

Comment: I've never seen that trick before, it's a new one on me :) In that case, then no the identity column would not be required. Of course, then it becomes a design preference whether one or two CTEs are used in getting the results.